# Git SSH checkout fails with Jenkins and GitLab

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gitlab

When I attempt a build on my Jenkins job that is configured to checkout from GitLab I am getting below error output (truncated)  :

```
    ....................
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@10.777.77.777:root/xxx.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1242)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
    ....................................................
        ....................................................
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@10.777.77.777:root/xxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Load key "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/gitlabjenkinsdemo@tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh1964800292912998995.key": invalid format
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@10.170.8.204: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2681)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2102)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:624)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
... 11 more
```

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE

I am trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline as per this post [Jenkins_Gitlab](https://faun.pub/quick-and-easy-ci-cd-with-gitlab-and-jenkins-ba7821032e9c)

I expected that the private key I added should enable checkout out of the box (Note : Both Jenkins server and Gitlab server are running on the same Debian instance).

In the ~/.ssh directory I have the following :

```
root@myservername:~/.ssh# ls -ld
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 18 15:30 .
```

In the source code management tab of my Jenkins job I have also added the ***SSH link that I extracted from my project*** in Gitlab. However what I am unsure of is the message below that the project is showing in Gitlab :

[image: GITLABERROR]

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both Jenkins server and Gitlab server are running on the same Debian instance

Ideally, they would run with their own associated service account, not "`root`".

But still, even as `root`, this should work.
Check which private SSH key you have added, and make sure, at least for testing, it wasn't one protected with a passphrase (meaning the [private key file does *not* have a `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED` line in it](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129727))

That might be a cause for the `jenkins-gitclient-ssh1964800292912998995.key": invalid format` you have.
(That or you have copied the private key file content with CRLF instead of LF as end-of-line)
(or you have copied a public key, where a private one was expected, or vice-versa)

From the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238362/discussion-between-vonc-and-golide):

- the private key had to be registered again in Jenkins (making sure its eol -- end-of-line -- are LF, not CRLF)
- the branch needs to be renamed:

> My repo had `master` when I did `git init`, so had to rename branch to `main` when I set the GitLab remote

Comment: I have copied  the correct key (private key) . SSH key was created as passphrase free (I have checked for Proc-Type:4,Encrypted also as a quick verification) .. On another note how do I check whether I have copied the file content with CRLF , or alternatively  amend how I copy .

Comment: @Golide OK. Could you try, from your Jenkins server, as root(I suppose, meaning as the account whose ~/.ssh has the public and private key) to do a ssh -i /path/to/private/key -Tv git@10.777.77.777, and see if GitLab authenticate you correctly.

Comment: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.777.77.777 ([10.777.77.777]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Remote: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_ZW.UTF-8
Welcome to GitLab, @root!

Comment: this is working

Comment: @Golide Is it possible Jenkins is not running as root? (although, it should still work, since Jenkins is not looking for your ~root/.ssh/ private key, but should have it stored in its own private credentials)

Comment: I will have to see how I can check for that first - Do you have an idea? . . regardless I still think  I need to check  if line endings are correct .. Why ? Because I have had to copy the private key from my SSH terminal to a textfile on my local Windows filesystem -  then from the textfile to Jenkins config page .

Comment: @Golide `ps -eaf|grep jenkins`: see which account owns the process running jenkins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238362/discussion-between-vonc-and-golide).

Comment: Ok @VonC coming to chat